# iOS custom keyboard frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I am making a custom keyboard and I need to draw something above it. I know that apple disallowed to do that straight, but I'm going to try it myself.

What if I make keyboard's view transparent with the height of a window and place an opaque subview with buttons? In this case I can draw on that transparent view. Can I do that somehow? If not, can I get current view controller's view to draw on it? If yes, is it a bad idea?

Here what i've tried in my KeyboardViewController.m:

```
[self.view setAlpha:0.5];
[self setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen];
self.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

Comment: Post some code/images/something that you've tried. You won't get an answer for "How do I do X"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inputAccessoryView property of whatever control is firstResponder.